# How can i Remove Maximize,Minimize and Close icon in MDI Menustrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

iam using C#.Net Windows Application.In my project have different module that will be used by MDI..
            now what the problem is,i can open a new form mean they will display maximize,minimize and Close icon in both MDI and Menustrip.See Below Image...

[image]

How can i remove child forms icons(Maximize,Minimize and Close) from MenuStrip

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Don't use MDI.  Change your forms to TopLevel = false and use them as UserControls.

Comment: Why do you want that feature? I think this is by design and the MdiClient doesn't support that feature.

Comment: Here is a way http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c7c1bea-7f37-4786-acb4-5685f827f8f2/remove-child-forms-icon-from-mdi-menustrip

Comment: Core of the MDI windowing model is that the user can switch between windows, resize them and minimize them.  If you remove those controls then he can't do that anymore.  So there's just no point in using MDI anymore.  A plain UserControl works just as well.

Answer (score 6):

In winforms the area where those buttons are is called ControlBox if you do not want them to be displayed you should set the ControlBox property of the form to false

```
childForm.ControlBox = false;
```

But as pointed out in the comments you could use your forms as UserControls by just setting its TopLevel property to false

```
Form childForm = new Form()
childForm.TopLevel = false;
childForm.Parent = MainForm;
childForm.Show()
```

Doing that you can acomplish the same final result as an MDI form

Comment: Also useful to be able to remove forms (assuming you want to show more than one as you were thinking of MDI):    
foreach (Control cntrl in panellContols.Controls)
      panellContols.Controls.Remove(cntrl);

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is solve for what you search

in first you should set all properties

```
formborderstyle = None
ControlBox = false
MaximizeBox = false
MinimizeBox = false
showicon = false
```

and **DO NOT SET** Windowstate = maximized

secondly when you create object from this form

```
form1 form= new Student();
form.MdiParent = this;
form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
form.Show();
```